# Unique pointer initializaton in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get some practice with smart pointers (specifically unique_ptr), but my compiler doesn't support C++14 so I cant use make_unique, which is what I think I'd need to use. Are there any alternatives to make_unique that work in C++11? Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <memory>
    using namespace std;

    unique_ptr<SavingsAccount> unqPtr = nullptr;
    string uName, uPwd;

    int main()
    {
        bool done = false;
        while(!done)
        {
            int decision = showMenuOptions();
            switch(decision)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << "Enter your name: ";
                    getline(cin, uName);
                    // Error is here.. alternatives to make_unique??
                    unqSaPtr(new SavingsAccount(uName, uPwd));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // ...
                    break;
                case 3:
                   done = false;
                   break;
               default:
                   cerr << "Invalid option." << endl;
                  continue; 
        }
    }
}
```

If any other code is needed for reference, just let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for `unqPtr.reset(new SavingsAccount(uName, uPwd));` ?